# Attack animations lasts for 1 frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Hello I am making a 2D top down student game in Unity. I am stuck at the animation part where My attack animations lasts for 1 frame and then goes straight back to Idle. Using C# in visual studio:

```
void Update () {
    Move ();    
    float lastInputX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float lastInputY = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (lastInputX != 0 || lastInputY != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walking", true);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", lastInputX);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", lastInputY);
        anim.Play("Walk");
    }
    else if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", true);
        //StartCoroutine(Attack());
        anim.Play("Attack");
    }
    else 
    {
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", false);
        anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
        anim.Play("Idle");
    }
    float inputX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float inputY = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

    anim.SetFloat("SpeedX", inputX);
    anim.SetFloat("SpeedY", inputY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this but if the behaviour of CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown() is the same as Input.GetButtonDown() it will return true during the frame the user pressed down, but it will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again.

This means that on the first frame the user pressed the button it will trigger the Attack animation but next frame will return false and trigger the Idle animation.

Also, I'm not sure why are you calling anim.Play() on each animation, the purpose of Animator parameters is to trigger the animation when a given value is present.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the update loop runs on every frame, and on every frame you are setting the animation. Remove the if else from the update loop. In the animator controller you can make transitions so after the attack it goes back to idle, walking, or whatever you want, you do not need to code what happens at the end of an animation.